# Multiplication of two integer gives wrong value (ATMEL ATmega32A)

Tags: atmel

The data and Uart data is added here.I really can't understand what's the problem..I tried different kinda solutions as changing data types,values,prints...

I'm using ATmega32A which is programmed by USBasp.

Here is the code:
https://hastebin.com/soqexihoni.cs
Here is the UART Com. log:
https://hastebin.com/muwekuniva.hs

Another version I change the data type of the variables.
But only 'temp' variable changed.I could read it.But the problem still goes on..
" temp = (5*data*100)/1024; " doesn't give any logical result..

Thanks for every comment (y)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with the data types and how you write the code.
The code `(5*data*100)/1024` performs the operation in integer and then, converts it in float because `temp` is float.

You could try something like:

```
temp = ((float)5 * (float)data * (float)100) / (float)1024;
```

It might be over the top to cast all variables, but that is the principle.